# Under what conditions has a Fourier transform no poles?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

Under what conditions the Fourier transform defined by

$$ F(u)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \, f(x) \exp(iux) $$

I think that the conditions for the function $ f(x) $ are

- $ f(x) $ has no poles on the real line
- or $ f(x)$ has compact support on the interval $ (a,b) $
- for $ |x| \sim \infty $ the function has the exponential decay $ O(e^{a|x|^{1+e}}) $ for positive $a$, $e$

are there other possibilities?

Comment: The function $x^{-1/2}(x+1)^{-1}$ on $x\geq0$ does not fulfil any of your criteria.